# List<T> add method in C#

Tags: c#, list, c#-2.0

As I know. List Add method works as below.

```
List<string> cities = new List<string>();
cities.Add("New York");
cities.Add("Mumbai");
cities.Add("Berlin");
cities.Add("Istanbul");
```

If I designed the data structure as this

```
List<object> lstObj = new List<object>();            
if (true)  // string members
{
    cities.Add("New York");
    cities.Add("Istanbul");
}
else // List obj members here 
{
    List<object> AListObject= new List<object>();
    cities.Add(AListObject);  // how to handle this?
}
```

Does the List `Add` method works or not if I add different types members in the same function.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to convert an Xml file to List<object> data structure. There are some sub items (subListObj) must be add to the main list obj(mainListObj). Thanks.

Comment: There are already classes that convert an XML file into a tree structure. Why not use one of those?

Comment: @Mark Byers. Sounds like a great news. unfortunately I don't know none of them yet. Could you please give me a link. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a `List<object>` to a `List<string>`. The only thing you can add to list of strings is strings (or null references). You could use this instead:

```
List<object> cities = new List<object>();
```

But this seems like a bad design. When you use `object` as the generic type of a collection you effectively lose all the benefits of type-safety.

For parsing XML I'd suggest you look at [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).

Comment: Could you please give me a tree structure resource/tutorial link particularly focus on Xml convert to the tree data structure thanks.

Comment: A little pity, I can't use Linq yet for .Net 2.0 Only.

Comment: @Nano HE: Sorry I didn't see the c#-2.0 tag. Try XmlDocument instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since you created a list of type `object` you can add anything to it since every type can be boxed into an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can add anything to a `List<object>`, so if you changed `cities` to a `List<object>` then your code would work.

```
var list = new List<object>();

list.Add("hello");
list.Add(1);
list.Add(new List<bool>());

Console.WriteLine(list.Count());
```

Having said that, it's almost certainly a bad way to code whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<object> AListObject = new List<object>();
foreach (object o in AListObject)
{
    string s = o as string;
    if (s != null)
    {
        cities.Add(s);
    }
}
```

If you could use LINQ from .NET 3.5 than you could do next:

```
List<object> AListObject = new List<object>();
cities.AddRange(AListObject.OfType<string>());
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no point using a generic list with object as the type parameter, might as well use a System.Collections.ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [List.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method for adding multiple items to a list.

```
cities.AddRange(AListObject);
```

However, you'll have problems trying to add `object` to a list of `string`.

Comment: I don't think that's what he is asking.

Comment: My main List obj nested by multi sub objs(include several sub List objs ). The multi items may be 'string', 'int', 'list' etc.